# CPU x86 - external interrupt invokes exception handler

Tags: x86, cpu, interrupt

If I will be wrong, please correct me. In x86 architecture, there are 256 interrupt vectors. The first 32 are exceptions/internal interrupts/synchronous interrupts. What will happen if external device provides as interrupt vector vector that is lower than 33? Or it cannot happen? If not so, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers for all your questions depends on the actual `CPU` family, the current processor mode (starting with the 80286 CPU) and external and internal specialised interrupt circuits (8259 PIC for 8086, LAPIC in 80386, x- and x2-apic in modern CPU families) . For example, the 8086 interrupt architecture had capacity for a maximum of 64 different `maskable` hardware interrupts and it was possible to assign a block of vectors to any 8-vector boundary in the interrupt table. Particularly, the `IBM PC-XT` had 8 maskable interrupt vectors starting from vector 8.